How fix error when building PyOpenGL-accelerate 3.1.7 on Windows 11
I am using Python 3.13.0 on Windows 11 (fully updated) with Visual Studio 2022 (also up-to-date). numpy has been installed alongside Python. When running "pip install pyopengl-accelerate", pyopengl-accelerate v3.1.7 is getting downloaded and the build process is being started using VS 2022's C/C++ compiler. After a bunch of file compilations, I am getting the following error:
  Error compiling Cython file:
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
      cdef int PyArray_CheckScalar( object )
      int NPY_ARRAY_CARRAY
      int NPY_ARRAY_FORCECAST
      int PyArray_ISCARRAY( np.ndarray instance )
      int PyArray_ISCARRAY_RO( np.ndarray instance )
      cdef np.ndarray PyArray_Zeros(int nd, np.Py_intptr_t* dims, np.dtype, int fortran)
                                            ^
  ------------------------------------------------------------

  src\numpy_formathandler.pyx:22:42: 'Py_intptr_t' is not a type identifier

Can I fix this myself, and if so, how?

See https://github.com/cgohlke/pyopengl-build

I think one solution might be to install numpy 1.26.0 instead of v2.x.
